# a query to find persons who likes at least 2

Tags: sql, database, self-join

At first I was asked to find persons who likes someone with blue eyes which was easy, then I was asked to find persons who likes at least 2 people with green eyes, when I extended my first query to solve the second task, my query resulted nothing.

the query was ran on 2 tables (Persons and Likes)
Persons contains  Persons, personB_id ==> Persons)

It would be appreciated if anyone can help me writing the second query :)

below you can find the query I wrote for the first task and the second task respectively.

Task1:

```
SELECT distinct p1.name
FROM Persons as p1,Persons as p2, Likes as l 
where p1.id =l.personA_id
And p2.id = l.personB_id
And p2.eyeColor= "blue"
```

Task2:

```
SELECT distinct p1.name
FROM Persons as p1,Persons as p2, Likes as l, Persons as p3
where p1.id =l.personA_id
And p2.id = l.personB_id
And p3.id = l.personB_id
And p2.id = l.personB_id <> p3.id = l.personB_id
And p2.eyeColor= "green"
And p3.eyeColor= "green"
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, for example `"Odd column-name"`. Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'green'`.

Comment: (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Another useful thing that you may or may not know is that googling with 'site:stackoverflow.com' limits searching to site stackoverflow.com and that the stackoverflow.com search facility is poor.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking "group by":

```
SELECT pa.name
FROM Likes l JOIN
     Persons pa
     ON pa.id = l.personA_id JOIN
     Persons pb
     ON pb.id = l.personB_id
WHERE pb.eyeColor = 'green'
GROUP BY pa.name, pa.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  This is the 21st Century and this syntax has been obsolete for more than two decades.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- The `GROUP BY` includes the person id, just in case two people have the same name.